# ncat command works on command line but not on php script

Tags: php

I have this command:

```
echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n' | ncat www.website.com 80
```

Which works perfectly fine in the command line. It doesn't, however, work in the php script:

```
<?php

$html = system("echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n' | ncat www.website.com 80");

print $html;

?>
```

Instead of returning the correct html, it returns a "Your browser sent a request the server could not understand" error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're writing PHP, therefore the `\n` in your string were parsed by PHP into actual newlines:

```
$html = system("echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n' | ncat www.website.com 80");
                                       ^^^^^
```

and what you ended up sending to the shell that `system()` started up looked like:

```
echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.0

'| ncat www.website.com 80
```

Try

```
$html = system("echo -e 'GET / HTTP/1.0\\n\\n' | ncat www.website.com 80");
                                       ^--^---note these
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
<?php

$html = system("echo 'GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n' | ncat www.website.com 80");

print $html;

?>
```

I had to remove the -e from the echo command. I checked the packets on Wireshark and what was being sent was this:

```
-e GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Go figure...